# How can I use Wow64GetThreadContext?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe7

How can I use `Wow64GetThreadContext` correctly in x64? The function is not defined in `Winapi.Windows.pas` in DelphiXE7.

I tried this however.

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Winapi.Windows;

const
  WOW64_SIZE_OF_80387_REGISTERS = 80;
  WOW64_MAXIMUM_SUPPORTED_EXTENSION = 512;
  WOW64_CONTEXT_i386 = $00010000;   // this assumes that i386 and
  WOW64_CONTEXT_i486 = $00010000;   // i486 have identical context records
  WOW64_CONTEXT_CONTROL = LongInt(WOW64_CONTEXT_i386 or $00000001); // SS:SP, CS:IP, FLAGS, BP
  WOW64_CONTEXT_INTEGER = LongInt(WOW64_CONTEXT_i386 or $00000002); // AX, BX, CX, DX, SI, DI
  WOW64_CONTEXT_SEGMENTS = LongInt(WOW64_CONTEXT_i386 or $00000004);    // DS, ES, FS, GS
  WOW64_CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT = LongInt(WOW64_CONTEXT_i386 or $00000008);  // 387 state
  WOW64_CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS = LongInt(WOW64_CONTEXT_i386 or $00000010); // DB 0-3,6,7
  WOW64_CONTEXT_EXTENDED_REGISTERS = LongInt(WOW64_CONTEXT_i386 or $00000020);  // cpu specific extensions
  WOW64_CONTEXT_FULL = (WOW64_CONTEXT_CONTROL or WOW64_CONTEXT_INTEGER or WOW64_CONTEXT_SEGMENTS);
  WOW64_CONTEXT_ALL = (WOW64_CONTEXT_CONTROL or WOW64_CONTEXT_INTEGER or WOW64_CONTEXT_SEGMENTS or  WOW64_CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT or WOW64_CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS or  WOW64_CONTEXT_EXTENDED_REGISTERS);
  WOW64_CONTEXT_XSTATE = LongInt(WOW64_CONTEXT_i386 or $00000040);
  WOW64_CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_ACTIVE = $08000000;
  WOW64_CONTEXT_SERVICE_ACTIVE = $10000000;
  WOW64_CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_REQUEST = $40000000;
  WOW64_CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_REPORTING = $80000000;


type
  PWOW64_FLOATING_SAVE_AREA = ^WOW64_FLOATING_SAVE_AREA;
  WOW64_FLOATING_SAVE_AREA = record
      ControlWord: DWORD;
      StatusWord: DWORD;
      TagWord: DWORD;
      ErrorOffset: DWORD;
      ErrorSelector: DWORD;
      DataOffset: DWORD;
      DataSelector: DWORD;
      RegisterArea: Array[0..WOW64_SIZE_OF_80387_REGISTERS-1] of BYTE;
      Cr0NpxState: DWORD;
  end;

  PWOW64_CONTEXT = ^WOW64_CONTEXT;
  WOW64_CONTEXT = record
    // The flags values within this flag control the contents of
    // a CONTEXT record.
    //
    // If the context record is used as an input parameter, then
    // for each portion of the context record controlled by a flag
    // whose value is set, it is assumed that that portion of the
    // context record contains valid context. If the context record
    // is being used to modify a threads context, then only that
    // portion of the threads context will be modified.
    //
    // If the context record is used as an IN OUT parameter to capture
    // the context of a thread, then only those portions of the thread's
    // context corresponding to set flags will be returned.
    //
    // The context record is never used as an OUT only parameter.
    //

    ContextFlags: DWORD ;

    //
    // This section is specified/returned if CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS is
    // set in ContextFlags.  Note that CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS is NOT
    // included in CONTEXT_FULL.
    //

    Dr0: DWORD;
    Dr1: DWORD;
    Dr2: DWORD;
    Dr3: DWORD;
    Dr6: DWORD;
    Dr7: DWORD;

    //
    // This section is specified/returned if the
    // ContextFlags word contians the flag CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT.
    //

    FloatSave: WOW64_FLOATING_SAVE_AREA;

    //
    // This section is specified/returned if the
    // ContextFlags word contians the flag CONTEXT_SEGMENTS.
    //

    SegGs: DWORD;
    SegFs: DWORD;
    SegEs: DWORD;
    SegDs: DWORD;

    //
    // This section is specified/returned if the
    // ContextFlags word contians the flag CONTEXT_INTEGER.
    //

    Edi: DWORD;
    Esi: DWORD;
    Ebx: DWORD;
    Edx: DWORD;
    Ecx: DWORD;
    Eax: DWORD;

    //
    // This section is specified/returned if the
    // ContextFlags word contians the flag CONTEXT_CONTROL.
    //

    Ebp: DWORD;
    Eip: DWORD;
    SegCs: DWORD;              // MUST BE SANITIZED
    EFlags: DWORD;             // MUST BE SANITIZED
    Esp: DWORD;
    SegSs: DWORD;

    //
    // This section is specified/returned if the ContextFlags word
    // contains the flag CONTEXT_EXTENDED_REGISTERS.
    // The format and contexts are processor specific
    //

    ExtendedRegisters: Array[0..WOW64_MAXIMUM_SUPPORTED_EXTENSION-1] of BYTE;
  end;

function Wow64GetThreadContext(
  {_In_}     hThread: THandle;
  {_Inout_}  var lpContext: WOW64_CONTEXT
): BOOL; WINAPI; external Kernel32 delayed;

var
  TargetContext: WOW64_CONTEXT;
begin
  TargetContext.ContextFlags := WOW64_CONTEXT_FULL;
  Wow64GetThreadContext(GetCurrentThread, TargetContext);
  WriteLn(GetLastError); // 87 - ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: @TLama It will help others facing the same problem ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681665.aspx):

> You cannot get a valid context for a running thread. Use the Wow64SuspendThread function to suspend the thread before calling Wow64GetThreadContext.
>
> If you call Wow64GetThreadContext for the current thread, the function returns successfully; however, the context returned is not valid.

In other words, you must not call `Wow64GetThreadContext` on the executing thread.

And further from the documentation:

> This function is intended for 64-bit applications. It is not supported on 32-bit Windows; such calls fail and set the last error code to ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION. A 32-bit application can call this function on a WOW64 thread; the result is the same as calling the GetThreadContext function.

It only makes sense to call this function from a 64 bit process passing the handle of a 32 bit thread. In other words, the thread that you pass must be from a different process.

So, my belief is that you are executing from a 64 bit process and specifying a 64 bit thread. The function fails because the thread you specified was not a 32 bit WOW64 thread.

Some other problems:

1. You need to use the `WOW64_CONTEXT` struct rather than `CONTEXT`.
2. As documented, you should only call `GetLastError` when the function fails, as indicated by the return value. This is the single most common mistake made by novice Win32 programmers.

Comment: Ah! That seems to be it!

Comment: I cannot stress strongly enough that you should read the documentation in full, with extreme care. Read it twice. Make sure you understand it all. This advice holds for all Win32 programming.